# Counting number of files in subfolders and writing to text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion, cmd, count

I need to regularly count the number of files in many subdirectories from many computers.  I'm looking for a batch file that will output a recursive count of all files, and then output this to a text file.  Ideally, I want this without having to type out the complex name for each subdirectory.

Here is an example of what I have:

> Parent_directory.
>
> ```
> Sub_directory_A. 1000 files
>
> Sub_directory_B. 2000 files
>
> Sub_directory_C. 3000 files
> ```

I've found this code online, but it only counts one subfolder, and I have to navigate into that subfolder first:  `attrib.exe /s /D *.*|find /c /v "" >> filecount.txt.`  Therefore, this is very close.
How can I start in my parent directory and get a count of the files in folders A, B, and C broken out individually and then copied to a .txt file?

Comment: What about this: `for /D %I in ("*") do dir /B /A:-D-H-S "%~I\*.*" | find /C /V ""` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Comment: `for /D %I in ("*") do @(<NUL set /P ="%~fI: " &2>NUL dir /B /A:-D "%~I\*.*" | find /C /V "")`  is a possible alternative to @aschipfl's approach.

Comment: @JosefZ this is very very close.  The output I get only counts files one folder deep.  The .txt file created contains all of the sub-folder names (that's perfect).
How can I search recursive for all of the files in all of the sub-folders?  
My parent directory contains subdirectories A, B, and C and. Each of these contains many more subs and lots of files.  I only need the total count, not per sub folder. 

Parent. 
    Sub_directory_A (1000 total files). 
       6folders. 
         more subs. 
Parent. 
    Sub_directory_B (2000 total files). 
       7folders. 
         more subs.

Comment: Try [`for /D /r %I in …`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html).

Comment: the /r gave the output (into the text file) of each subfolder and the number of files separately.  This might be useful for some situations. However, for me, /s was needed.  This gives on the subfolders and ALL files contained within.    My final code is or /D %I in ("*") do @(<NUL set /P ="%~fI: " &2>NUL dir /B /A:-D /s "%~I\*.*" | find /C /V "") >>filecount.txt

I confirmed the count, and it perfectly matches 
thanks for all the help